# Отображение XML документов с использованием таблиц CSS

Tags: css, xml

Отобразить в браузере результат применения стиля к файлу.

```
/* File Name: Inventory01.css */

BOOK
    {display:block;
    margin-top:12pt;     
    font-size:10pt}  
TITLE        
    {font-style:italic}

AUTHOR   
   {font-weight:bold}

_______________
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- File Name: Inventory01.xml -->

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Inventory01.css"?>

<INVENTORY>
   <BOOK>
      <TITLE>The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Mark Twain</AUTHOR>
      <BINDING>mass market paperback</BINDING>
      <PAGES>298</PAGES>
      <PRICE>$5.49</PRICE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <TITLE>Leaves of Grass</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Walt Whitman</AUTHOR>
      <BINDING>hardcover</BINDING>
      <PAGES>462</PAGES>
      <PRICE>$7.75</PRICE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <TITLE>The Legend of Sleepy Hollow</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Washington Irving</AUTHOR>
      <BINDING>mass market paperback</BINDING>
      <PAGES>98</PAGES>
      <PRICE>$2.95</PRICE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <TITLE>The Marble Faun</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Nathaniel Hawthorne</AUTHOR>
      <BINDING>trade paperback</BINDING>
      <PAGES>473</PAGES>
      <PRICE>$10.95</PRICE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <TITLE>Moby-Dick</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Herman Melville</AUTHOR>
      <BINDING>hardcover</BINDING>
      <PAGES>724</PAGES>
      <PRICE>$9.95</PRICE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <TITLE>The Portrait of a Lady</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Henry James</AUTHOR>
      <BINDING>mass market paperback</BINDING>
      <PAGES>256</PAGES>
      <PRICE>$4.95</PRICE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <TITLE>The Scarlet Letter</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Nathaniel Hawthorne</AUTHOR>
      <BINDING>trade paperback</BINDING>
      <PAGES>253</PAGES>
      <PRICE>$4.25</PRICE>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
      <TITLE>The Turn of the Screw</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Henry James</AUTHOR>
      <BINDING>trade paperback</BINDING>
      <PAGES>384</PAGES>
      <PRICE>$3.35</PRICE>
   </BOOK>
</INVENTORY>
```

Comment: @Lana15, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите подсветить синтаксис? Заюзайте JS библиотеку какую-нибудь. Например, вот: https://highlightjs.org/